# PHP - Find Specific Value in Array (multidimensional)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the an array, in which I store one value from the database like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT token FROM advertisement_clicks  WHERE (username=:username OR ip=:ipcheck)");
$stmt->bindParam(":username",$userdata["username"]); 
$stmt->bindParam(":ipcheck",$ipcheck);
$stmt->execute();

$data = array();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So, that gives me: `array("token","token");`

When I print it:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [token] => 677E2114AA26BA4351A686917652C7E1BA67A32D ) [1] => Array ( [token] => C42190F3D72C5BB6BB6B68488D1D4662A8D2A138 ) )
```

I then have a loop, that loops all the tokens. In that loop, I try to search for a specific token, and if it that token matches, it will be marked as "seen":

```
function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['token'] === $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my loop:

```
$icon = "not-seen";
foreach($d as $value){
   $token = $value["token"];
   $searchParam = searchForId($token, $data);
   if($searchParam == $token){
     $icon = "seen";
   }                            
}
```

However, `searchForid()` simply returns `0`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: note: you're adding another dimension `$data[] = $stmt-`, just `$data = ` and why not search for the token by way of query?

Comment: @Ghost Ah, good catch! I have changed that now in OP.

Comment: and using the function is superfluous, `$token = $value["token"];` is already a string, and then you load it into your function, then looping it which doesn't make sense, why not just search for it on the first loop, scrap the function and don't forget to add `break;` once found, or just flat out `select where` the token on the query

Comment: @Ghost i assume both $d and $data are arrays with different tokens, OP wants to compare each token from $d with each token of $data. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: $d is just a query that takes data from table in my database. $value["token"] is a column from the database

Comment: @BasvanStein the OP has the answer to that, i don't even know if thats a typo. `searchForId` doesn't make sense, it just returns the key, so `if($searchParam == $token)` comparison won't pan out

Comment: @Ghost yep I also pointed that.. oliverbj: what do you mean by quary? Is it the same as $data?? In that case you should use a single loop.. but then what do you want to do. Pleas be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here you can see a PHP fiddle that works

```
$data = array();
$data[] = array('token'=>'123');
$data[] = array('token'=>'456');

function searchForId($id, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['token'] === $id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

$icon = "not-seen";
foreach($data as $value){
   $token = $value["token"];
   $searchParam = searchForId($token, $data);
   if($searchParam){
     $icon = "seen";
   }                            
}
echo $icon;
```

It echos `'seen'` which is expected since I compare the same array values, now assuming that your `$d` variable has different tokens, it should still work this way.

That means that your $d array does not contain what you claim it contains, could you `print_r` this variable and post it in your answer?

Comment: I have changed that in my OP as well. However, it still doesn't work. Now Searchforid() returns "0"

Comment: That's just the query that selects the results from the database. The loop works

Comment: You are sure `$token = $value["token"];` has the correct value?

Comment: yes, it have the same values as the one in the array.

Comment: If $searchParam == $token never will be true, what should I use then?

Comment: @oliverbj i added a suggestion, though it does not fix your loop. Maybe you can add echo statements in the loop to debug what happpens? (The search finction should work imho)

Comment: You can use `if(isset($searchParam) )` because searchParam will be null when the search fails. You can also let the function return true or false instead (thats more nice I think)

Comment: Alright. I will be sure to add that. However, I still can't get it to return true? If the $value["token"] output is the same as let's say the first result in the array, then why wouldn't it return true?

Comment: @oliverbj try with == to see if maybe the objects did not match

Comment: With "==" didn't change anything. Still returns "false"

Comment: @oliverbj I posted a working example, please see what is different in your code.

Comment: Just a quick question: why do you add $data[] now? I changed that to $data. Or is it the same, but just "hardcoded" to match my question?

Comment: @oliverbj its the same but hardcoded, since I do not have a database. `fetchAll` returns a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Any reason you put the $icon outside the loop? It have to check for each looped value.

Comment: @oliverbj no, that was just for testing.